# Using SkiaSharp to create crossed out circle filled with color

Tags: c#, wpf, skiasharp, avaloniaui

I am new to working with skiasharp with avalonia. I looked at the documentation and examples of how to make some basic shapes, like circles, rectangles, etc. Can anyone give advice or suggestion on how to make a crossed circle filled with color? I think it would be best to do UserControl, something like in wpf.

Answer (score 0):

How you package this up (UserControl) really depends on the use case and intention of the UI element.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="Vol2" 
         Width="25" 
         Height="25">
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse x:Name="MyCirlce" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black">
        </Ellipse>
        <Rectangle Height="50" Fill="White" Width="15" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="42.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"></RotateTransform>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

A `ViewBox` scales it's content, like an SVG.

We then plop a `Canvas` in there and add our `Ellipse`. We then add a `Rectangle` and position in (Left, Right) and then add a `RotateTransform`.

This should get you going.